# The media library can not be loaded on initial startup

Tags: ios, swift, realm, media-library

I want to list and display the songs of the media library on the initial screen after starting up.
When I start up for the first time, a popup of permission to access the media library will be displayed. And no song of the media library is loaded.

Once exit the application and open it again I can display the songs of the media library without problems.

How do I load it at first boot?

AppDelegate;

```
let realm:Realm
var library:[MPMediaItem]

override init() {
    realm = try! Realm()

    let query = MPMediaQuery.songs()
    guard let items = query.items else {
        self.library = []
        print("No song loaded")
        return
    }
    self.library = items
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions  launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let userSongs = realm.objects(UserSong.self)
    if userSongs.count == 0 {
        setLibrary()
    }
}


func setLibrary() {
    let request = GetLibraryRequest(library: library)
    let songs = try! request.response()
    for song in songs {
        try! self.realm.write {
            self.realm.add(song)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just query again after you added it into realm

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread on the Apple developer forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/53219), if permission hasn't been granted to access the media library yet, calls to `MPMediaQuery` won't halt code execution; it'll keep executing. So you'll need to perform the fetch only after you've actually gotten permission from the user. :)

From iOS 9.3 onwards, there's an API that lets you check the status of your app's permissions, and to request it if you otherwise you don't have it. It then lets you specify a closure that will execute when permission is granted, which would be best for when you want to properly grab the items for the first time.

Cross-posting from the Apple forums (Original answer courtesy of TheCD):

```
func exampleMethod() {  
        if #available(iOS 9.3, *) {  
            let authorizationStatus = MPMediaLibrary.authorizationStatus()  
            switch authorizationStatus {  
            case .NotDetermined:  
                // Show the permission prompt.  
                MPMediaLibrary.requestAuthorization({[weak self] (newAuthorizationStatus: MPMediaLibraryAuthorizationStatus) in  
                    // Try again after the prompt is dismissed.  
                    self?.exampleMethod()  
                    })  
            case .Denied, .Restricted:  
                // Do not use MPMediaQuery.  
                return  
            default:  
                // Proceed as usual.  
                break  
            }  
        }  
        // Do stuff with MPMediaQuery here...  
}
```

On a final note, you shouldn't be executing code in the the `init()` method of your app delegate. It's possible the app hasn't finished setting up at this point, and may lead to unpredictable behavior.

You should create a method that checks for the permissions and performs the necessary actions beyond that point, and call it from your `application(application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` method implementation. :)